# What port should I choose to run the SocketTextStreamWordCount sample

Tags: apache-flink

Feeling my way around Flink.  I've generated the SocketTextStreamWordCount from the [quickstart](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.8/scala_api_quickstart.html) and discovered quickly the recommended usage

```
SocketTextStreamWordCount <host> <port>
```

However, I have no idea what port to choose.  The QuickStart docs don't reveal much, and while I suspect I need to submit the JobManager's port as an argument, I get a **Connection Refused** when I configure the [default port](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/config.html) (6123).

Appreciate any help or hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SocketTextStreamWordCount` example program receives its input from a network socket. The port parameter of the program does not refer to the JobManager port, but to the socket port against which the program connects to read input. Therefore you have to open a socket before you can start the program.

From the JavaDocs of the `SocketTextStreamWordCount.java` class:

> This example shows an implementation of WordCount with data from a
>   text socket. To run the example make sure that the service providing
>   the text data is already up and running.
>
> To start an example socket text stream on your local machine run
>   netcat from a command line: `nc -lk 9999`, where the parameter
>   specifies the port number.

If you follow these instructions, you should execute the program as

```
SocketTextStreamWordCount localhost 9999
```